# Are bitcoin testnet addresses taxed?

Tags: wallet, testnet

[Here](http://test.insight.is/address/mkB48VbaG1Ng3K9ouuLmAFLik664ymVNrD) is a testnet address I've been experimenting with,

[Here](http://test.insight.is/tx/b42199f7ee392be8ccffed05f501e32a2a4783aa8e3e96667edfaf12ad1d0397) is some test BTC leaving the address,

I didn't initiate the transfer though, is this a feature of the testnet to keep the faucets stocked perhaps?

My wallet is provided by TP's bitcoin faucet from [here](http://tpfaucet.appspot.com/).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, even in Testnet, there is no legitimate reason for coins to be leaving your address without you initiating it.

It's possible you somehow sent the transaction by mistake, or that someone else (perhaps a virus or Trojan) gained access to your private keys.

Comment: No, it must be because it's hosted by the faucet provider, the same thing happened with another wallet I created using their service, I suppose it makes kind of sense that they do that :/

Comment: @derrend: Oh, I didn't read carefully. Right, if your wallet is hosted by someone else, with them having access to the keys, then they can certainly spend the coins. Kind of obnoxious, though, even on Testnet.